# while testing a component with Chai a error is being displayed Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined , how to solve it?

Tags: reactjs, testing, mocha.js, chai

I am new to react and as well as testing in react, so while I am trying write a simple test to test whether a component is rendered by using  `expect(container.length).to.equal(1)`.
But I am getting an error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined.

```
describe('local test', () => {
    it('should render', () => {
        let container = shallow( < App / > )
        expect(container.length).to.equal(1)
    })
})
```

This code for my App.js

```
class App extends Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <div className ="grid-container">
        <header>
          <a href="/">React Shopping Cart</a>
        </header>
        <main>
          <div className="content">
            <div className="main">
              <Filter />
              <Product></Product>
            </div>
          </div>
        </main>   
      </div>
     )
  }
}
```

Comment: Where is `indexOf` in your code?

Comment: yes there is no indexOf but when i run the test cases it gives me a cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined, i think the problem is with container.length

Comment: Can't reproduce it. Can you remove the `Filter` and `Product` components and try again?